# Get Logs in gradle as present in maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, gradle

By doing `mvn clean install`, I got all the logs in console and can see all the test cases running.

However using gradle commands like `./gradlew build` doesn't show anything like that. In the last it just shows build success.

PFB below mvn and gradle logs that are comming.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how I can see logs in gradle as while present in mvn clean install.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To show standard out and standard error of the test JVM(s) on the console, use

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

More options are documented in the [Gradle Test DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html).